# Windows 10 IOT Editions on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: windows-iot

I know that Windows 10 IOT Core is is supported on raspberry pi and that it can run headless.

I'd like to know whether other editions of Windows 10 IOT (specifically Enterprise or Retail) can run on raspberry pi 3 or whether Core is the only supported Windows 10 IOT edition?

Our ultimate goal is to install, for example, Windows 10 IOT Enterprise on the raspberry pi with a .net framework 3.5 based user interface.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean running desktop programs?

Comment: Yes, we use some of the other Windows IOT versions for Kiosks and those kinds of things - and if possible we would want to use the pi for .net framework forms based applications

Comment: You can only run Windows 10 UWP apps

Comment: You will never get x86 binaries or WinForms apps to run on the Pi with Microsoft operating systems. Embrace IoT Core , the UWP and the ARM architecture or stick to Intel/AMD systems.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment you can only run Core on Rasbperry Pi 3+

The reason is that Windows IoT core is targeted at low cost, open source or educational embedded devices and only allows a single UWA kiosk like application to run on it. Its free and easy to use if you are a C# house.

Windows IoT Enterprise is basically Windows Embedded with a new name and is the "IoT" version that supports x86, like the Edison.  It basically means you get a normal Windows 10 experience with allot of "enterprise" features. This is targeted for the guys with the money though - like healthcare and finance providers and you cannot just download it, even if you got MSDN.