# Windows IoT Enterprise on Raspberry PI 3B

Tags: gpio, hardware, wireless, rpi.gpio

I want run applications x86 on Raspberry Pi 3.
Is possible install Windows IoT Enterprise on RaspberryPi 3 ?

Comment: You cannot (usefully) run x86 applications on any model of pi, period, whether or not Windows IoT works.  I am not sure that you mean literally what you've written there though.

Comment: I can Install Windows IoT Enterprise on RaspberryPi3?

Comment: Don't think so, if this is up-to-date: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/60857/5538 When I wrote my previous comment I did not realize what the "Enterprise" qualifier meant.  If it is x86 only it cannot be used on a Pi.  All Pi's are ARM based.

Comment: thanks for you help.. God Bless you.. now I understand all..!!! :)

Comment: hi. @goldilocks. I want work a projects with SBC that can run Windows 10 of desktop.  you know that SBC´s can run Windows 10 of desktop. see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5EXNfHYPfQ. you understandme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you 'just' want to run x86 apps on the Pi, try [ExaGear Desktop](https://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/exagear-desktop-features-and-prices/).
It's not perfect, but it *might* give you what you want.

Comment: How is the performance on that? I'm extremely skeptical of their website's claims.

Comment: I want run a app with .Netframework 4.0. I can run this apps  on ExaGear Desktop...........??

Comment: Best to ask the ExaGear guys, I'm afraid. I think our experience on here, collectively, is a little low!

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot run Windows 10 IOT Enterprise. As is, the IOT flavor of enterprise is just a headless optimized version of the desktop version. The enterprise version still requires an x86 processor.

The RPi has an ARM processor which is fundamentally incompatible with your goals.

> Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is a full version of Windows 10 that delivers enterprise manageability and security to IoT solutions. It is designed for powerful industry devices used in retail, manufacturing, healthcare, and other industries. **Note: Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is a binary equivalent to Windows 10 Enterprise.** *(emphasis mine)*
>
> > https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/windows-iot